# Como usar o sweet alert antes de apagar linhas do MySQL

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Estou tentando utilizar o [`sweet alert`](http://lipis.github.io/bootstrap-sweetalert/) pra confirmar a intenção de apagar uma linha da tabela MySQL, mas acho que não estou sabendo como fazer.

Usando o `alert` simples faço assim:

```
<a title='Remover linha' class= 'deletrow' href='deletrow.php?id=$id'><i class='fa fa-remove resultsfa5'></i></a>
```

No arquivo `deletrow.php` está o MySQL pra apagar a linha e antes de apagar o JS pede a confirmação:

```
$('.deletrow').on('click', function () {
    return confirm('Tem certeza que deseja apagar esta linha?');
});
```

Mas tentando com o `sweet alert` não dá certo, porque quando coloco o `href` dentro da tag `<a>` (sem o `href` funciona) ele apenas pisca na tela.

Neste <kbd>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xe096w10/74/)</kbd> dá pra reproduzir o problema. Basta tirar o `href` de dentro da tag  que já funciona, senão apenas pisca... mas daí então como aponto para o arquivo onde está a `query` do MySQL?

Segue abaixo o snippet funcional (com `button`):

```js
      document.querySelector('.sweet-1').onclick = function(){
        swal("Nice alert!");
      };
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://tristanedwards.me/u/SweetAlert/lib/sweet-alert.js"></script>
<link href="http://tristanedwards.me/u/SweetAlert/lib/sweet-alert.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2 text-center">
          <p><button class="btn btn-primary sweet-1">Abrir alert</button></p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Então como posso utilizar com `<a href...>`, ou, mesmo usando com `<button>`  onde incluo a regra pra apagar a linha?

Comment: Eu utilizo o próprio modal do bootstrap para esses casos, passando o id do elemento deletado no link para um input oculto no modal, onde posso cancelar ou aceitar a deleção. Atenderia também o seu problema?

Comment: @adrianosymphony, valeu, mas quero usar `sweet alert` mesmo.  A resposta abaixo resolveu. Valeu.

Comment: OK, mas por questão de curiosidade fica um exemplo de forma dinâmica http://jsbin.com/vasoforowe/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @adrianosymphony é esse mesmo que to usando! ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode criar uma função que passa o ID como parâmetro e ao clicar no botão "OK" ele redireciona para a página deletar! Como abaixo:

```
function confirmExcluir(id)
{
  swal({
      title: "Excluir",
      text: "Confirma a exclusão?",
      type: "error",
      showCancelButton: false,
      confirmButtonClass: 'btn-success',
      confirmButtonText: 'OK!',
      closeOnConfirm: false
   }, function () {
      window.location.href = 'deletrow.php?id=' + id;   
   });
}
```

E no html fica assim:

```
<a title='Remover linha' class='deletrow' onclick="confirmExcluir($id)" href='javascript:;'><i class='fa fa-remove resultsfa5'></i></a>
```